# EntityFramework (ORM) object names and domain model names - how to avoid duplicates?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, naming-conventions

Let's say I have a project where I use Entity Framework, but I want to use my own classes instead of the EF classes.

Reasons for using my own classes:

- Easy to add properties in code
- Easy to derive and inherit
- Less binding to the database

Now, my database has table names like `User` and `Conference`.

However, In my domain project, I also call my files `User.cs` and `Conference.cs`.

That means I suddenly have two objects with the same naming, which is usually very annoying to work with, because you have to use namespaces all the time to know the difference.

**My question is how to solve this problem?**

My ideas:

- Prefix all database tables with 'db'. I usually do this, but in this case, I cannot change the database
- Prefix or postfix all C# classes with "Poco" or something similar

I just don't like any of my ideas.

How do you usually do this?

Comment: So you can't change the database names and you don't want to change the c# class names but you want them to be different? That's some catch, that Catch-22

Comment: @Colin the type of answer i expected ;) I hoped for magic beans and I couldn't see some very obvious solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without more background but it sounds like you are using the Entity Framework designer to generate EF classes. This is known as the "Model First" [workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134.aspx). Have you considered using the [Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907#codefirst) / Code Only workflow? When doing code first you can have POCO classes that have no knowledge of the database, EF, or data annotations. The mapping between the database and your POCOs can be done externally in the the [DBContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx) or in [EntityTypeConfiguration](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/11/28/composing-entity-framework-fluent-configurations.aspx) classes.

You should be able to achieve your goal of decoupling from EF with just one set of objects via code first.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the above answer, the database table name *User* (or *Users* as many DB designers prefer) is the identifier for the persistence store for the object `User` that's defined in your code file **User.cs**. None of these identifiers *share the same space*, so there should be no confusion.  Indeed, they are named similarly to create a loose coupling across spaces (data store, code, development environment) so you can maintain sanity and others can read your code.